Pandas DataFrame uses more memory than it claimed
My program is very simple. I run it in Jupyter Notebook. It loads data from MongoDB. I tried to store the data as pandas.DataFrame at first.
import pandas as pd
import pymongo

mongo = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
data = pd.DataFrame(mongo['stock']['em_users_detail'].find({}).limit(1000000))

My windows task manager tells me that my program is using about 3000MB of memory. I checked the memory usage in Python. The following code gives me the same result:
import psutil
import os

psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2

I then checked the memory data is using via two approaches:
# the first approach
data.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() / 1024 ** 2

# the second appraoch
from pympler import asizeof
asizeof.asizeof(data) / 1024 ** 2

The first approach yields 837MB while the second yields 1675MB, which is considerably larger. However, both results are far smaller than the memory my program is using (3000MB). So I have two questions:

Why do the results from these appraches differ so much?
What else could be using my Python memory?

So it seems like a memory leak problem. I doubted the problem is with MongoDB, so I tried to store the data using list.
import pymongo

mongo = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
data = list(mongo['stock']['em_users_detail'].find({}).limit(1000000))

This time my Python program uses 3800MB of memory and asizeof shows that data occupies 3500MB of memory which sort of adds up.
So I think the problem doesn't seem to be related with MongoDB. Instead, it seems to be related with pandas.DataFrame.
I am awared that there is a similar question here: Dataframe memory usage different between sys.getsizeof and pandas memory_usage. But the thing here is even when setting deep=True when calling memory_usage on my DataFrame, the results still don't quite add up.
